# Can we consume multiple message from JMS queue by single read?

Tags: jms, adapter, message-queue, fusion, oracle-fusion-middleware

I only want to call my `JMS Adapter` once, and in return *I want maximum of 100 messages to be returned in response*. Is it even possible ?

I am using `12C` of `Fusion middleware`.

Please any points will be very helpful.

Comment: I am not sure about Fusion, but a standard JMS receive API will get one message at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, This is not Possible. JMS is not very rich in functionality and can read only one message at a time.

This is the basic behavior of JMS at least till the 12C Version.

In fusion, Oracle might enhance it.